# Lock & Unlock the screen via WLAN - Keyboard

Tags: macos, screen-lock

**I use Synergy to share my mouse and keyboard across different computers.**

Now i want to lock and unlock the screen of my mac. I have activated corners, so when i move my mouse at the left corner of my screen, it gets dark.

> But when i want to unlock the screen, nothing happens! My Mac doesn't
>   recognize any mouse movements or keyboard actions.

I need to lock & unlock the mac screen for testing purpose.

Is there any script command which can lock and unlock my screen by itself?

> For example: lock my screen for 5 secondes, and unlock it again after
>   this period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to work something together in automator but I am not too familiar with that app.

I would check and see if you have wake for network access on. 
In System Preferences->Energy Saver there is a checkbox to "wake for network access". If that is unchecked it is unlikely your computer will respond since I believe that app is based on Networking

[UPDATE]: Doing a quick search it appears other users are experiencing this issue with synergy and lion. take a look [here](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/search/?q=sleep&Submit=search&t=question)